# Getting a "Content types that are available to this Document Set have been added or removed"

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, designer-workflow, document-set

I am creating document sets through workflows. **Edit:** I just tested and I'm getting this message for manually created documents sets as well. Every new document set is showing the message:

```
Content types that are available to this Document Set have been added or removed.
```

In its welcome page. **Edit:** There is also a link to "update the document set". Clicking on it just refreshes the page, but the error message and the link are still there.

I have read about it, and people around the internet generally suggest three solutions:

- Updating the `docset_LastRefresh` property of the document set. One guy said this on MSDN years ago and many people have been parroting it ever since. Problem is, it just doesn't work. The property is changed but other than that nothing happens.
- Provisioning the document set. Can't be done via CAML for obvious reasons, and when I try calling the `provision` method in an event receiver, I get the exception below. Since I'm coding in the same machine where the server is, and I have the assembly, I'm assuming this is because the solution is sandboxed.

  ```
  Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLongOperationState' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.900.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
  ```
- Creating the document sets from a Visual Studio workflow instead of a SPD one. Unfortunately, I have to deliver the solution as a sandbox one, and that excludes VS workflows.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in my case, I was getting this message on every document set because the whole site collection was corrupted. And it got corrupted because I made a deploy of the same schemas to the same site many times. According to some people with certifications and years of experience that I've talked to, this messes up the collection the site belongs to.

So now when testing on my test environment, I am continuously destroying and recreating my site collection everytime I need to deploy my schemas. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With an out of the box document set this can be caused by having the list content type and the site content type out of sync. Just remove the list content type and re-add it from the site ct and it will fix itself up.